# Run elevated powershell command from command prompt

Tags: powershell, command-line

```
powershell.exe Start-Process powershell.exe "set-executionpolicy" -Verb runAs
```

The above command will run a powershell window as admin and execute the command before it, however, if I want to make it say `set-executionpolicy bypass`, it will error out. How can I pass this parameter through the top command?

Below is the error I get when I pass said parameter:

```
    Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'bypass'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe set-executionpolicy bypass -Verb runAs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: And if you put it under quotation marks? "set-executionpolicy bypass"

Comment: I did. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Start-Process` accepts an array of arguments in order to pass into created process. So, in order to launch an elevated Powershell that would execute a `Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet you need to wrap the arguments into an array.

```
start-process -filepath powershell.exe -argumentlist @('-command','Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass') -verb runas
```

As a side note, you probably want to set execution policy with `-scope` argument for it to actually be effective once that process ends.

Comment: That works. Thank you. Can you explain the -scope part and where to put it?

Comment: `get-help set-executionpolicy` :) `-scope` determines which policy is to be modified. Values usable when starting elevated are `localmachine` and `machinepolicy`, the second can be overridden by domain policy IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `–ExecutionPolicy` switch directly on `PowerShell.exe` to bypass the execution policy.

```
powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: NONE of these answered the ORIGINAL question. How do you run from the "run" command an elevated PowerShell session ("Windows cannot find start-process)? You HAVE to use cmd /c originally, so how then do you run an elevated PowerShell that doe snot close from 'cmd/c'? It appears it's NOT possible.